# Информация о функциях/переменных в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, методы, переменные

Подскажите пожалуйста команды, с помощью которых находясь в IDE я могу получить информацию о методах/функциях которые я использую? Допустим я использую регулярное выражение re.match - и хочу узнать что оно делает, и какие виды аргументов принимает?
Или например я создал переменную, и хочу посмотреть какие операции я к ней могу применить?

Comment: Укажите в вопросе IDE, которым пользуетесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Касаемо того, как получить информацию о функции. Просто зажимаете CTRL и кликаете левой кнопкой по названии функции, если у Вас Windows. На MacOS + CMD + левый клик.

Вас "отправит" в реализацию этой функции и выше, конечно, же описание, что эта функция делает, какие аргументы принимает и что возвращает.

> я создал переменную, и хочу посмотреть какие операции я к ней могу применить?

Тут в принципе сложно что-то посоветовать. Сама IDE Вам предложит методы, которые можно к этой переменной применить. Например в PyCharm можно получить список строковых функций, которые можно применить к переменной, в которой хранится текст.

```py
example = "Hello World!"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ну это зависит от IDE. Если вы PyCharm используете, то поставьте курсор на функцию и нажмите комбинацию клавиш ctrl+b(для Windows). Откроется исходный файл с этой функцией и можно будет посмотреть, что она делает.
Если вы используете Ultimate версию, то можно навести указатель на функцию и появится документация. Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Если вы используете Ultimate версию" - это и в Community версии работает. Кстати, можно принудительно эту подсказку вызвать через Ctrl-Q

Comment: Давно не пользовался Community, возможно и там можно